# I need to develop a one-page design

Tags: theme-development, templates

I know how to add the scrolling effect, I just needed help that how should I code the onePage.php template by which I can handle different themes for the divs i.e. ABOUT, EVENTS ... each div has a different layout & background color..

Hardcoding the divs is not the solution .. I can also dynamically add the divs to the homepage .. but the main question is how to handle different layouts for each div?

Right now using this as my Home Page Template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/
get_header();
?>
<div id="container">
    <a name="top"></a>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order', //post_title
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'child_of' => 0,
        'parent' => -1,
        'exclude_tree' => '6',
        'number' => '',
        'offset' => 0,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $pages = get_pages($args);
    //start loop
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
        $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_data->ID ), 'index-post-thumbnail' );
    ?>
    <div class='page' id='<?php echo "$slug" ?>'><a name='<?php echo "$slug" ?>'></a>
        <div class="page-content">    
            <h2 class="entry-title"><?php echo "$title" ?></h2>
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="page-featuredImage">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Use CSS and style the IDs that you've assigned here `<div class='page' id='<?php echo "$slug" ?>'>`

Comment: I can do that too, but the page layout is different for each div

Comment: Just got an Idea, I can use get_template_part('template-name');  instead of directly calling the content .. and add a custom post type to select template-name while adding a new page .. 

I hope it works ..

Comment: Brother Hassan Alvi, Lynda.com and Treehouse both have courses on how to develop one page style site using wordpress, I think that will be a nice start for you. Wish you Good Luck ! –

Comment: Dear Arif, thanks for the suggestion ... its quite helpful, but need kind of detailed customization ... 

I have another question, while adding the menu items, I want to modify the wp_nav_menu to use href="#<slug>" instead of regular permalinks .., is there anyway to achieve that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it right @Hassan Alvi, you should use get_template_part() for each stage of your one pager.

Dont use id use specific class instead, it's more object oriented.

It will make you code a lot more readable and more easy to maintain!

Comment: Got it .. is there any way I can select the template without using a custom post type?

Comment: You can use page ID it's depend if you need to call multiple things of the same type like Job or Employee bio for example.

Comment: I want it to be dynamic.. So I want to select different template for different pages while creating a new one..

Comment: Do you create a theme that can be use everywhere or it's only for one website if it's for a website only you can use Advanced custom field plugin you create a custom field to select your templates part. I think you should consider to use shortcode too.

Comment: I already know about that.. Just needed to know if there is any other better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: The easiest way to make full custom order one pager is to create a repeater field with select page or post field and you select the page you want to show in the order you want. in each page you add a custom field for the template part. i think that could be the more easily way to modified it.